# How to compare strings after rendering with render_to_response in Django?

Tags: python, django, templates, render

I want to refactor many template files related to HTML written by Django.
The files are messy and consist of "copy & paste".
Since our project will long, this "Technical debt" should be returned.

Thus, I'd wanted to write the test between before and after refactoring.

I only want to compare these renderings, contexts are not but needed here and creating contexts for the tests tires me because there are many template files.
So I created the context which always return "Hoge" as dummy and it worked well on shell.

```
class X(Context):
   def __getitem__(self, key):
       return "Hoge"

t = Template("b{{ m }}a")
t.render(X()) #-> bHogea
```

However when I used the similar method (render_to_string) in the file related to test, it emitted "VariableDoesNotExist" Exception.
Of course, on shell, "render_to_string" works well.

It seems that "django.template.base.Variable._resolve_lookup" occur the exception, I assign the method, returning the former Context "X()", to _resolve_lookup. Like the following.

```
Variable._resolve_lookup = lambda him, context: X()
```

(--I know this way is really bad but my purpose is only testing to compare the renderings)
However, after that, soon the following exception was caused.

```
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'xxx_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
```

I also know these Exceptions are happened in the template file whose want  some response from Django.

Then I heard here.
What things should I do?
Should I try to test step by step?

Comment: The context may contain strings, but it may contain any kind of datastructure. And the some of the template tags may act on those. You cannot just provide a dummy value. You'll need to identify, for each template, what they expect in their context and supply an appopriate sample.

Comment: Thank you. I've realized it's not impossible but too difficult from "Act" of your word. Certainly, to archive this, I must give the class having some procedures or complex data structures. So it may be dull and its codes will be dirty. I try to search another way. Thanks.